# How to add a Button to the end of Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to create a UI similar to Apple's in Game Center Settings, where there is a tappable link at the end of text:

> [image]

I'm using SwiftUI. I tried to combine `Text` and `Button` in several ways:

```
Form {
    Text("A social gaming service that lets you interact with friends, track and compare scores and achievements, challenge other players, and compete in mulitplayer games.")
    Button("See how your data is managed...", action: {})

    Button(action: {}, label: {
        Text("A social gaming service that lets you interact with friends, track and compare scores and achievements, challenge other players, and compete in mulitplayer games.").foregroundColor(.black)
        Text("See how your data is managed...")
    })

    Group {
        Text("A social gaming service that lets you interact with friends, track and compare scores and achievements, challenge other players, and compete in mulitplayer games.")
        Button("See how your data is managed...", action: {})
    }

    HStack {
        Text("A social gaming service that lets you interact with friends, track and compare scores and achievements, challenge other players, and compete in mulitplayer games.")
        Button("See how your data is managed...", action: {})
    }
}
```

But none of these combinations worked:

> [image]

I would ideally like to avoid [using an NSAttributedString](http://www.gfrigerio.com/nsattributedstring-in-swiftui/), as I want to use SwiftUI components, and only want the blue portion to be tappable.

How do I append a `Button` to `Text` so that it's text is aligned to the baseline of the text?

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that this type of layout will be available in SwiftUI anytime soon. The major complexity comes from the fact that the `Button` text must have some knowledge about (A) the frame of the `Text` block (e.g. to know where to place overflowing content like the word "data" in the original example), (B) to align the `Button`'s first baseline to the `Text`'s last baseline, and (C) to align the `Button`'s leading edge to the exact end of `Text` on the last line (e.g. it can't just to the right of the frame, otherwise you'll get HStack behavior).

One workaround is to follow a different pattern (i.e. the one in the Safari Settings) where the components are vertically placed:

> [image]

This is a far easier layout to achieve in SwiftUI:

```
Section(footer:
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Allow websites to check if Apple Pay is enabled and if you have an Apple Card account.")
        Button("About Safari & Privacy...", action: {})
}) {
    EmptyView()
}
```